# If $X$ is the set of positive integers, how can some topology on it not satisfy the first axiom of countability?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of integers. Obviously, $X$ satisfies the second axiom of countability, which implies it also implies the first axiom of countability. Regardless of the topology!

Let $X$ be Appert's space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appert_topology). My textbook says this space does not satisfy the first axiom of countability. How this is possible?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why must $X$ satisfy the second axiom?

Comment: $X$ contains a countable number of elements- the set of positive integers. The number of base sets also have to be countable. I think....?

Comment: Why? The positive integers have uncountably many subsets.

Comment: My logic was: the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathfrak{N_{0}}$. The number of possible base sets, if every possible combination of positive integers is considered, is $2^{\mathfrak{N_{0}}}$. Isn't this again a countable number?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: True. Thanks. This should give me some direction.

Comment: Another example of a countable space which is not first countable is the [Arens–Fort space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space), which I describe a bit more fully in [this previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190495/8348).

Answer (score 3):

The countability axioms refer to the cardinality of a base, not the cardinality of the ground set. As you mention in the comments, a topology on a countable set may require up to $2^{\aleph_0}$ open sets for its base, which is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

First let us recall the definiton of Apperts topology.

Let $X$ be the set of positive integers. Let $N(n,E)$ denote the number of integers in a set $E\subset X$ which are less than or equal to $n$. We describe Apperts topology on $X$ by declaring open any set which excludes the integer 1, or any set $E$ containing 1 for which $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{N(n,E)}{n}=1$.

Now we will pove that it is not first countable.

**Proof:** $X$ is not first countable, since the point 1 hasn't a countable local base at 1. Suppose that $\{B_n\}_n$ were a countable base at 1. Then each $B_n$ must be infinite, so we can select a point $x_n\in B_n$ such that $x_n>10^n$; then $U_n=X\setminus \{x_n\}_n$ does not contain any of the sets $B_n$, yet it is an open nbhd of 1, for $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{N(n,U)}{n}=1$.